Transcribing medical notes from 1878
I am attempting to transcribe the medical notes for Maria Coke in my family. I did a similar exercise in the past for my great-great-grandmother Martha Coke, and these records are for one of her sisters at a different lunatic asylum.
Maria was only in the asylum about 10 months, and as result, there are only 2.5 pages of notes. I believe I have managed to work through about 95% so far.
However, I do have a snag list, and this is first item.
Some of the subject matter might not be suitable for discussion, so I have clipped the extract to the bare minimum.
The extract:

This is my transcription:

Her mother stated she has been restless and xxx for several days, and that on the morning of the 26th of June she slipped down the stairs and cut …

It’s the word after restless that I can't make out. The word looks like it ends with ing. My guy is telling me it says sewing!

Update
I just realised that it would be a could idea to include the original statement, as made by her mother on the Order Paper:

Does that help?

I suspect this says raving (speaking uncontrollably).

Thanks!  That would make sense and complete the sentence.
